# Can I delete an application remotely using a Blackberry Enterprise Server?

Tags: deployment, remote, blackberry, bes

A client has rolled out a beta version of an application to a number of Blackberries manually and now wants to delete it ahead of rolling out the new version.

Is it possible to do this remotely using the BES (Blackberry Enterprise Server)?

I'm guessing so but if it is how (just rough pointers would be great) and does it need any user interaction (and indeed could the user interfere with or prevent the deletion)?

Apologies for a relatively trivial question, I just don't have a BES to play around with right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my team found this which seemed useful:

http://www.blackberry.com/btsc/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=KB05392&sliceId=1&docTypeID=DT_SUPPORTISSUE_1_1&dialogID=138856095&stateId=1%200%20138848963

A more detailed description of how to delete apps.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible with the OTA (Over-the-Air) Feature of the BlackBerry Mobile Data System (free Service on your BES).

Look at this link
[BlackBerry Mobile Data System / Features](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/services/mobile.jsp#tab_tab_features)